# Excluding a case in קנין but קנין remains valid

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, maseches-kiddushin

I heard of an idea that when it comes to קנינים (Acquisitions)*if the קנין cannot be done in every instance, the קנין does can not apply at all.*

Example: (Forgetting רש"י or other commentaries) In קידושין ג ע״ב the Gemara concludes a statement (which started on ג ע״א) that חליפין cannot be done in קידושין due to it being able to be done with less then a פרוטה (amount of money or bronze). I know רש"י as well as others give there understanding. But for this example I heard that it couldn't be done because since חליפין can be done with less then a פרוטה and קידושין can't,.

So therefore since there is a case where חליפין wouldn't work, the whole process of חליפין is disqualified.

Is this a known idea throughout ש״ס?
And are there any examples of places were we disqualify one case but the קנין can still be used in a different way. (Example: Disqualify less then a פרוטה, but more then a פרוטה would work.)

PS. I'm aware this is a technical question, so please feel free to ask for more detail or explanation.

Comment: שטר can be less than pruta value. The point here may be that chalipin and Kessef are relative to a same main kind of Kinyan.

Comment: @kouty Not quite sure what your comment is. But I'm not focused on the example I gave. It was an example. I'm curious if there's an idea in ש״ס where if there's a case where a kinyan doesn't work, that types of kinyan is all together void (even though there are cases where it would work)

Comment: The logical structure is no easy to understand.  Here,  you have chalipin which works too good and include extragkiddushinic cases,  so it is not adapted for kiddushin.   In your first ennunciation you told about a different hypothetic case.  A kinyan,  let's imagine,  which is not good for kiddushin of a woman with dark hair; this kinyan would not work even for green hair woman.  No?